# The code gives a parse error I can't find what the error is

Tags: html

The code gives a parse error I can't find what the error is, the curlys brackets aren't wrong I'm trying to model the equation, v = \sqrt\frac{19.6*mass}{Cd*1.229*area}

```php
<?php
  function terminalVelocity($mass,$cd,$area) {

  $velocity = (sqrt(19.6 * $mass / $cd * 1.229 * $area));
  return $volume;
}

if ($_POST['enter']) {
  $mass = ($_POST['mass']);
  $area = ($_POST['area']);
  $cd = ($_POST['cd']);

  if ($mass > 0 && $front > 0) {
    $result = terminalVelocity($mass,$cd,$area);
    echo "The terminal velocity of the is: ". round($result,2);
} else {
    echo "You must have a value for each input";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you add the *exact* error/stack trace you're getting to the body of your question?

Comment: 2 x if??? if->elseif->else

Comment: it says parse error

Comment: Your first if-block isn't closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_POST['enter']) {
  $mass = ($_POST['mass']);
  $area = ($_POST['area']);
  $cd = ($_POST['cd']);

  if ($mass > 0 && $front > 0) {
    $result = terminalVelocity($mass,$cd,$area);
    echo "The terminal velocity of the is: ". round($result,2);
} else {
    echo "You must have a value for each input";
}
```

The number of `{`s compared with `}`s doesn't match.  Try:

```
if ($_POST['enter']) {
  $mass = ($_POST['mass']);
  $area = ($_POST['area']);
  $cd = ($_POST['cd']);

  if ($mass > 0 && $front > 0) {
    $result = terminalVelocity($mass,$cd,$area);
    echo "The terminal velocity of the is: ". round($result,2);
  }
} else {
    echo "You must have a value for each input";
}
```

Comment: no I don't this line is right
$velocity = (sqrt(19.6 * $mass / $cd * 1.229 * $area));

Comment: @KevinLuu : I just noticed and edited it.

Answer (score -1):

Check this

```
<?php
  function terminalVelocity($mass,$cd,$area) {

  $velocity = (sqrt(19.6 * $mass / $cd * 1.229 * $area));
  return $volume;
}

if ($_POST['enter']) {
  $mass = ($_POST['mass']);
  $area = ($_POST['area']);
  $cd = ($_POST['cd']);

} elseif ($mass > 0 && $front > 0) {
    $result = terminalVelocity($mass,$cd,$area);
    echo "The terminal velocity of the is: ". round($result,2);
} else {
    echo "You must have a value for each input";
}
?>
```